# Handling quotes in Postgresql queries using PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I'm trying to pass a variable in a postgresql query using php.

Here's a shorten version of the script :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM neighborhood_stats WHERE neighborhood LIKE '$_POST[submit]%'";
$query = pg_exec($db, $sql);
```

My issue is that the variable `$_POST['submit']` contains a quotation mark `baie-d'urfé`

I've tried using :

```
$var = "baie-d'urfé";
$new = pg_escape_string($var);

//output baie-d"urfé
```

The problem is that the query doesn't work with `baie-d"urfé`. I've tested using the value `baie-d''urfé` and this works. However, I can't find a way to obtain the latter. I've tried using a mix of `pg_escape_string()` and `str_replace()` but I can't make it work.

Comment: Don't manually escape the data. Use [prepared statements with parameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare) instead, which isn't just safer, but will also solve problems like this.

Comment: Also make sure the DB connection and the db/table/columns have appropriate charset set,

Comment: Use pg_query_params() and a place holder in your piece of SQL. That solves your problem, but most important it protects you from SQL injection.